# How to get value in object based on another value

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object

I could use some help cycling through an object and getting the difference in price between two products.  For example, what is the difference in price between the big hammer and the small hammer?

Here's what I have so far

```
var myarray = [{product: "big hammer", price: 32},{product: "small hammer", price: 22},{product: "wrench", price: 15},{product: "saw", price: 55}];

getPriceDifference(myarray[0].product);


function getPriceDifference(currentProduct){

   if(currentProduct === "Big Hammer"){

     //do something...this is where I am stuck

   }



}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably have your function accept two products and then return the difference, otherwise how does one know which price to compare it to?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @pilchard That makes sense.  How do I then go get the price of the two specified products?  This is kind of where I get stuck in that the product name is in the same object as the price.  I am a novice developer, so a basic direction without code would be helpful.

Comment: @Prime The expected output would be the difference in price between two products.  For example, the difference between the big hammer and the small hammer is $10, so the function would return 10.

Comment: Am not sure what the answer exactly would be. As I understand the function should get a value of a difference between two objects? Then in the function one parameter should be added like otherProduct. Like getPriceDifference(currentProduct, otherProduct). Hope you can find an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of iterating over arrays

```js
myarray.map(item => {

})
```

```js
myarray.foreach(item => {

})
```

Or if you change the structure of your data to the following, you do not have to iterate.

```js
var products = {
  "big hammer": { price: 32 },
  "small hammer": { price: 22 },
  "wrench": { price: 15 },
  "saw": { price: 55 },
};

function getPriceDifference(product_1, product_2) {
  return Math.abs(products[product_1].price - products[product_2].price);
}

var difference = getPriceDifference("big hammer", "small hammer");
console.log(difference);
```

Comment: The solution I found to work is the one you posted about changing the structure of the object.  Once I did that and passed two arguments, I was able to get the right output.  Thank you.

Comment: @user2828701 : opt-in for such data model *'improvement*' is an extremely poor idea - imagine product name100 characters long, which is pretty normal for product name, but way too long for appropriate object property name. Another issue, you may run into when you need to have items with the same name at a different cost (e.g. due to discount), which you wouldn't be able to implement as object key names must be unique. Those may not be the case for you ***yet***, but it's a pure tech debt taken without any good reason.

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov thanks for the tip. I’ll take this into consideration and see how I might be able to tweak this solution

Comment: @user2828701 : *'>..see how..to tweak'* the point was that you really shouldn't. Your initial data structure was way more robust (with small suggestion maybe to add unique `id` property for each item). I would rather stick to either of 2 alternative solutions you got in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
var myarray = [{product: "big hammer", price: 32},{product: "small hammer", price: 22},{product: "wrench", price: 15},{product: "saw", price: 55}];

function getPriceDifference(first, second){

   for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){

   if(myarray[i]['product'] == first) price_first = myarray[i]['price'];
   if(myarray[i]['product'] == second) price_second = myarray[i]['price'];

   }

   return Math.abs(price_first - price_second);
}

console.log(getPriceDifference('small hammer', 'big hammer'));
```